# Statefulwidget does not refresh after AlertDialog is closed

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(220.w,155.h,0,0),
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        ChangeProfile(context);
                      });
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.wifi_protected_setup),
                  ),
                ),
```

This is the code that opens an AlertDialog to change the profile.

```
 void ChangeProfile(BuildContext context) {
      final pro = Provider.of<Pro>(context, listen: false);
      US(context);
      int count = 0;
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(
    
            builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
              return AlertDialog(
                // RoundedRectangleBorder - Dialog 화면 모서리 둥글게 조절
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                //Dialog Main Title
                title: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: 50.w,
                      height: 50.h,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        pro.currentProfile
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                //
                content: SizedBox(
                  width: 230.w,
                  height: 230.h,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox

(

                        width: 70.w,
                        height: 70.h,
                        child: OutlinedButton(
                          onPressed: (){
                            setState(() { // setState() 추가.
                              pro.currentProfile= 'image_profile/profile_1.png';
                            });
                          },
                          child: Image.asset('image_profile/profile_1.png'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 70.w,
                        height: 70.h,
                        child: OutlinedButton(
                          onPressed: (){
                            setState(() { // setState() 추가.
                              pro.currentProfile= 'image_profile/profile_2.png';
                            });
                          },
                          child: Image.asset('image_profile/profile_2.png'),
                        ),
                      ),
```

In this way, when the button in the AlertDialog is pressed, the currentProfile variable in the Provider is changed.

```
 actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: Text(
                  "닫기",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  });

                },
              ),
            ],
```

Click the close button and it will pop up

```
PrintImage(
                  imagetext: pro.currentProfile,
                  xsize: 100.0,
                  ysize: 100.0,
                  hhh: 90.0,
                ),
```

When the currentProfile variable changes, the parent widget will output something like this

The values inside the AlertDialog are also successfully changed and when I check using the StatefulBuilder it changes well in real time. When I close the AlertDialog, the parent widget does nothing.

When another TextButton is pressed, PrintImage responds to the changed currentProfile value.

Is there a way to close the AlertDialog and refresh the build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way.
return `showDialog` (which is Future) from your `changeProfile` method
Since `changeProfile` method returns a Future we can now use .then method on the `changeProfile` and can refresh the build using `setState`.

As soon as the alert dialog is closed future gets completed and .then method executes.

One Correction: The method name should start with lowerCamelCase so it should be changeProfile instead of ChangeProfile.

```
               Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(220.w,155.h,0,0),
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                        changeProfile(context).then((value) {
                         setState(() {
                           // update your widget
                         })
                       }
                      );                                          
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.wifi_protected_setup),
                  ),
                ),

Future<void> changeProfile(BuildContext context) {
      final pro = Provider.of<Pro>(context, listen: false);
      US(context);
      int count = 0;
      return showDialog<void>(
       // paste rest of your code here
      );
}
```

Comment: thank you. FUTURE is always difficult..

Comment: error: This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used. (use_of_void_result at [goodman] lib\3_userscreen\userscreen.dart:74) 에러가 뜹니다..